# Sanctuary `Maybe` refers to a value, but being used as type here

Tags: typescript, option-type, sanctuary

I have a function like this

```
export const createMemberId: (x: any) => Maybe<MemberId> = (x: any) => {
    try {
        return Just({
            memberId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(x),
        });
    } catch (e) {
        return Nothing;
    }
};
```

It gets `any` and return `Maybe<MemberId>`

But typescript show me this error

```
`Maybe` refers to a value, but being used as type here
```

What should I do?

Comment: This is the problem discussed in [sanctuary-js/sanctuary#649](https://github.com/sanctuary-js/sanctuary/issues/649), I believe.

Comment: I saw that issue but didn't find solution. Can you explain how should I do this?

Comment: The problem is that the `Maybe` export refers to [`S.Maybe`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#Maybe) rather than to a type constructor. This is one of several problems that currently prevent me from recommending the use of Sanctuary in a TypeScript project.